# Firefox 65 gives a blank page when minimized/maximized

Tags: release-juno, firefox, web-browser, minimize

I might be in the wrong place and maybe should report this to Mozilla, but no one else seems affected by searching around, so I believe it might be elementary OS-specific.

Since version 65, when you minimize Firefox by clicking the dock icon and maximize again, going to a new page or reloading the current one gives you a blank page. The pages loads, as you can see the site name and favicon, but nothing is displayed. Sometimes it happens right away, other times you have to minimize/ṃaximize a couple times. Also the hamburger menu is unresponsive. The only cure is to relaunch Firefox.

I tried so far:

- Disabling hardware acceleration
- Restarting Firefox in Safe Mode
- Clear cookies and cache
- Update to 65.0.1

It might be related [to this question.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18178/firefox-unresponsive-after-upgrade-to-version-65)

Theme is basic light, only add-on is AdGuard. Using Nouveau stock display driver.

I am on Juno 5.0 with all the latest updates, Dell XPS 9550.

Thank you.

Comment: I am really the only human being suffering from this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if no one had this problem, it seems that Firefox 66 fixed it. I will test it some more and report back.